# How can I create a 2D array in swift of a certain size with its values set to 0? Swift

Tags: swift

I have this defined variable which is supposed to be a 2d array of ints. How can I make it so that the 2D array is 4x4 and the values are all 0?

```
var table: [[Int]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.init(repeating:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init) initializer.

Example:

```
let row = Array(repeating: 0, count: 4) // [0, 0, 0, 0]

var table = Array(repeating: row, count: 4)
```

Result:

```
print(table)
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```